# Add an EventListener on an overlay

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a project, there are some pictures on a web page, when I click on them it opens an overlay with the fullsized picture. I want to add to this overlay an Event Listener so when we press an arrow (left or right) it shows the next or the previous picture. Unfortunetely, it doesn't work although I managed to add one and it works well:

```
document.getElementById('overlay').addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    e.currentTarget.style.display = 'none';
}, false);
```

Comment: You can use `this` inside the event handler to access the clicked element

Comment: Left and right arrows isnt click events, they are keypress events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot listen for key events on your overlay element, you'll have to do it on the document itself.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {    
    if (e.keyCode === 39) {
        alert('right')
    }

    if (e.keyCode === 37) {
        alert('left')
    }
});
```

You can check that here: https://jsfiddle.net/agk5xs2u/

Comment: Thanks, ok i think i'll just deal with it.